# How to install gcc 6 on Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, gcc, dnf

I'm trying to build CORE Network Emulator from source and I seem to have hit a gcc7 bug, so I want to install gcc 6.4.1 but when I try to run `dnf install gcc-6.4.1` I get the error No package gcc-6.4.1 available

Running `dnf list --all gcc` shows only version `7.1.1-3`

I downloaded gcc-6.4.1-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm from https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/se... but when I tried to run dnf install ./gcc-6.4.1-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm I got an error:

```
Problem: conflicting requests

    nothing provides cpp = 6.4.1-1.fc25 needed by gcc-6.4.1-1.fc25.x86_64
```

How can I install gcc-6.4.1?

Answer (score 0):

You need the corresponding version of the *cpp* package as a dependency.

https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/25/x86_64/c/cpp-6.4.1-1.fc25.x86_64.html

Comment: But I would need to install each dependency separately?  Can't I just find the `dnf` package from the previous version somewhere so that it will install all of the dependencies for me as `dnf install` usually does?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be dependency reconciliation in this instance